# ROS 2 Occupancy and Obstacle Mapping that uses robot footprint?

Tags: 2d-mapping, occupancy-grid, ir, create3

I am investigating obstacle and occupancy mapping using the seven IR intensity sensors of the Create3 robot.  (The acceptable range of these sensors is from 0.150 to 0.4 meters.)

Using slam-toolbox with localization turned off, I am able to generate occupancy data as long as a wall or obstacle is in view, but the robot footprint is not used to mark cells as free.

Is there a mapping package (that I can run without localization) that will use the robot's footprint in the occupancy calculation?

[image: Create3 IR Sensor Mapping With Slam-Toolbox]